# Context and React, best practises

Tags: reactjs

I have a project which contains (among other things) a list view of events, and then of course a unique page showing these events individually, you can easily understand there are two distinct path : /events/ and /events/:id
I added some filtering on events, and of course when I filter the list, and then click a specific event to see it, and then go back to the events list, it of course, forget about my filter.

Should I use Contexts or is there a specific way I didnt hear about ?

I also thought about having different path for all the filters (ie : /events/filter_type_1 etc etc with filter_type_1 being something human readable.)

What would be the more logical way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no there 3 ways to solve this:

## Store state in higher component

instead of storing state in your overviewView component. store it in the component above that does the routing. this way it wont get lost on navigation. (i dont like this approach).

## Persist state

You could persist the state to the `localStorage` and read this state when your component mounts. this way when you come back your state will have persisted.

```
localStorage.getItem("overviewCompnent_filter");
localStorage.setItem("overviewCompnent_filter",yourData);
```

## Externalize state

There are state libraries that help you put top level application state outside of react components like: mobx (my favorite) and redux. These libraries use the context api underneath to deliver the right state/values to your component and you can let them make it inject them as props in your component (so it's like the first option but a cleaner solution).

This way you can keep all your top level state together and not have to give it all the way down your component tree.